# Pandas dataframe integer column is in scientific notation in csv file when writing csv using df.to_csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataframe that is written to a csv file with a column of integer values like 1618240891297, but the table is displaying it in scientific notation 1.61824E+12. I can correct it by changing the **Number Format** in Excel from **General** to **Number**. Is there a way to make this change when writing the csv file using DataFrame.to_csv?

Comment: What happens if you open the CSV in notepad / notepad++?  I bet it's formatted correctly there, which means that the problem you encountered is a problem with how Excel displays the CSV contents, not with the contents of the CSV itself.  If this is true, then the correct answer is to change the number format as you already did, or to export to an xls file and pre-emptively change the format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `float_format` parameter of [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to control the output formatting.  For example:

```
df.to_csv('myfile.csv', sep=',', float_format='%.6f')   # write with precision .6
```

Comment: But I don't want it to be floating point. It's an int64. In Excel, the number in the _Formula Bar_ is the way I want it displayed. But the cell display with the _Number Format_ as _General_ displays it in scientific notation. If I convert the format to _Number_, it displays a floating point number with two decimal places of precision.